# will a jsf component update its parent?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I normally have issues updating a component with a child components update tag. how can I update the parent component when i have the following setup?

```
<p:dataTable id="myTable">
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="chkChkbx" 
    value="#{backBean.showCheckTransactions}" style="float:right; margin-left: 15px;">
        <f:ajax update="myTable" listener="#{backBean.toggleCheckTransactions}"/>
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Comment: The datatable is not a parent component. It is a previous component, but one like all others.

Comment: Have you already tried render="#{cc.parent.clientId}"

Answer (score -1):

Very simple solution. Use `p:ajax` (tag) instead of `f:ajax` (tag).